# Show an html block if a url is available

Tags: html

I need to show an html block if the specific link is available without using javascript. 
In other words I need to reverse behaviour of `object` tag with `data` attribute, for example:

```
<object data="error.src">My content</object>
```

Shows content if `error.src` is not available.

Comment: HTML is a markup language, it describes content, not logic. To evaluate conditions you need logic, so a language that allows to implement logic code and which is evaluated inside the browser. That means javascript. May we ask _why_ you insist on the "without using javascript"? It is a bit surprising...

Comment: Our partners afraid of any js code and we need to use a tricky solution with only browser logic.

Comment: Ah, the well known argument along the lines "please create a computer based solution for us, but we insist that you do not use computers for that, we heard they are insecure. "

Comment: Are you allowed to use a server side language?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this without some JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't looks quite right. I need to show an inner div only if outer object is loaded.

Comment: @foo I've just updated my answer, I guess sprinkling in some js is the only way to achieve what you need :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use some css like this to hide/display object with specific data attribute:

```
object{
  display:none;
}
object[data="error.src"]{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Damn you beat me to it. was just about to paste.  FYI he wanted the inverse of this.